# Joomla 2.5 adds duplicated meta tag canonical from other view into current view when cache is on

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla! 2.5.17 Stable version of Joomla. I have created a component that uses a code to add canonical URL:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag("some custom code");
$document->addCustomTag("<link rel=\"canonical\" href=\"$theCorrectCanonical\" />");
```

it is located in components/my-component/views/my-view/tmpl/default.php

Since i have a lots of views it is defined in each view for my-view, my-view2 etc.

It was working fine. The canonical link was added properly. Event if i had cache on.
And lately i have disabled modules i didn't need anymore. So i disabled them and website was working fine after this.
Suddenly i have discovered Google marks my pages as non-canonical.
After looking at the code of website i have noticed that the HTML head looks like this:

```
some custom code
<link rel="canonical" href="correct-url" />
<link rel="canonical" href="url-of-a-page-i-visited-second-ago" />
```

So it looks like, that for whatever crazy reason Joomla ads not only the correct canonical but also a canonical tag of other subpage i have visited second ago. Making Google believe it is a non-canonical of a other page.

I have tried to search for a solution, but didn't find any. Also i have noticed that when i disable cache in config with:

```
public $caching = '0';
```

And in Addons -> System cache (i disable it). It goes back to normal. It does not add the second meta tag of canonical.

Index.php of my template looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * @version                $Id: index.php 21518 2011-06-10 21:38:12Z chdemko $
 * @package                Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  Templates.beez_20
 * @copyright        Copyright (C) 2005 - 2011 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license                GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

$resourcesVersion = "1.1";
$this->setGenerator('');

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// check modules
$showRightColumn        = ($this->countModules('position-3') or $this->countModules('position-6') or $this->countModules('position-8'));
$showbottom                        = ($this->countModules('position-9') or $this->countModules('position-10') or $this->countModules('position-11'));
$showleft                        = ($this->countModules('position-4') or $this->countModules('position-7') or $this->countModules('position-5'));

if ($showRightColumn==0 and $showleft==0) {
        $showno = 0;
}

JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);

// get params
$color              = $this->params->get('templatecolor');
$logo               = $this->params->get('logo');
$navposition        = $this->params->get('navposition');
$app                = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc        = JFactory::getDocument();
$templateparams     = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>" >
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />          
some stylesheets embedded directly
some scripts embedded directly
a meta tag embedded directly
</head>
```

I run out of ideas why it behaves this way. I don't know from where the second canonical comes from. It is not set in the view currently displayed. Such canonical is only set by other view in the same component. But how this lands into other view code? And only with cache = on?

Do you have any clues i could follow to find what is the issue here?

Comment: You already have a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account.  Why not post your Joomla support question in the place where there are volunteers with intimate knowledge of Joomla?

Comment: @mickmackusa Are you sure about it?

Comment: That has been my experience, yes.  Your bounty indicates that my advice has not been well-received.  Good luck.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry if you felt this way. It was fine recommendation. And a good support! Unfortunately people who can know this are split here and there. Well... at least i hope bounty will help.

Comment: Cross posting is okay too, as far as I know.  ...J2.5 is a long way back.

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party extensions for SEF, structured data, opengraph, canonicals, redirects, etc?  I have found that many will add other SEO type "features" without asking.  Can you update your answer with any ones you have?